# Getting all users per application Azure Active Directory .NET Web Api C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to access the users in my application in Azure Active Directory using .NET Web API C#.
I have tried to get the users from the client:

```
await this.aadClient.Users.ExecuteAsync()
```

but it gets all the users in AD and not per application.
I have tried to get the members of the application:

```
var apps = await this.aadClient.Applications.Where(x => x.AppId == this.appId)
                                    .Expand(x => x.Members).ExecuteAsync();
var app = apps.CurrentPage.FirstOrDefault();
var members = app.Members.CurrentPage;
```

But the result is always empty although the appId is correct and I have 19 users in the application.

Does anybody know what the problem could be?

---

### Edit

Getting the client:

```
var context = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant]", false);

var aadClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(
                new Uri(new Uri("https://graph.windows.net"), [tenant]),
                async () => await context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net", new ClientCredential([clientId], [clientSecret])));
```

Comment: Users are under AAD, what do you mean of users in the application? The owners?

Comment: No, not the owners. You can add users into a client application (enterprise applications tab), so, only those could log in. In this case, we can have one directory but multiple application. I want to target the users in one application only.

Comment: I see, it should be `https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}/servicePrincipals/{servicePrincipalId}6f/appRoleAssignedTo`. You could refer to https://www.mercuryworks.com/tips-for-working-with-the-azure-active-directory-graph-api-2/

Comment: What should it be? I didn't understand.

Comment: I just found the graph api which will return the users assigned to the application. Haven't test it by using graph client. Will test it later.

Comment: I already have this graph URL. I won't be able to call the clients if I don't have it. And why do I need a service principal in this example?

Comment: Can you show me how you get the graph client? Service principal id is the object id of your enterprise app.

Comment: @CaiyiJu please see my edit

Comment: I am using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient NuGet Package

Comment: Then you should use `aadClient.ServicePrincipals.GetByObjectId("").AppRoleAssignedTo` to get the users. Just like the api I sent you.

Comment: I got this: {"odata.error":{"code":"Request_ResourceNotFound","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Resource 'id' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present."}}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ad graph client calls the ad graph api, the api to get assigned users to your application is

```
https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}/servicePrincipals/{servicePrincipalId}6f/appRoleAssignedTo
```

So the code should be

```
aadClient.ServicePrincipals.GetByObjectId("").AppRoleAssignedTo
```

You can find the service servicePrincipalId as below. It is the ObjectId of your enterprise application.

[image]

`Directory.Read.All` permission is required. Click App registrations->find your application(the same one provided the clientId)->API permission

[image]

Remember to click `Grant admin consent` button since this permission needs admin consent.

[image]

**Update:**
I can get the users assigned to the application successfully, here is the test code.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;

namespace ConsoleApp13
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Uri servicePointUri = new Uri("https://graph.windows.net");
                Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, "{tenant}");  
                var aadClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(
                                serviceRoot,
                                 getToken);

                var a = aadClient.ServicePrincipals.GetByObjectId("{objectId}").AppRoleAssignedTo.ExecuteAsync().Result;
                Console.WriteLine(a.CurrentPage.Count);

            }

            public static async Task<string> getToken()
            {
                var context = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}", false);
                return context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net", new ClientCredential("{client_id}", "{client_secret}")).Result.AccessToken;
            }
        }
    }
```

Make sure you have granted `Directory.Read.All` permission to your app. You can check it in the access token by [decoding the token](https://jwt.io/).

[image]

Comment: The same problem. The members are an empty list.

Comment: @SamySammour So there is no error, just return an empty list, right?

Comment: Yes, the same thing I got with the old code. "Using client.Applications from the NuGet Package"

Comment: @SamySammour Have you granted  `Directory.Read.All` permission to your application and click `grant admin consent`?

Comment: Yes, I did. Unfortunately the same.

Comment: @SamySammour I can get the users assigned to the application successfully, see my updated answer.